# clearInterval() doesnt work on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

This is what i do:

```
var scrolling;

$('#nw_scroll_down').on('mousedown', function(){
  scrolling = setInterval(function() {
      $('.mod_article').scrollTop( $('.mod_article').scrollTop() + 5 );
    },25);    
});

$('#nw_scroll_down').on('mouseup', function(){
  if (scrolling) {
    window.clearInterval(scrolling);
    scrolling = false;
  }
});
```

inside a $(document).ready(function(){});

Everything works fine until the line

```
window.clearInterval(scrolling);
```

This works fine on PC but not on iPad. Can anyone imagine why it doesnt work on the ipad (chrome browser)?

Comment: Have you checked that the `scrolling` variable equates to `true`? Is `mousedown`/`mouseup` supported in iOS or is there an alternative? Have you done any debugging at all?

Comment: can it have something to do with that if you click longer on a picture in ipad there pops up a menu to save the picture and stuff... so the way the scroller is designed to be cannot work in ipad at all?

Comment: debugging yes, if i comment out the line //window.clearI... and do some alert('stuff'); i get the message. so the variable is true.
dont know if mousedown/mouseup is supported, but i guess not in the way like on pc.. damn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `mousedown`, you should make use of `touchstart` and `touchend` events for iPad as detailed in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html) or [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Touch_events).

Try this:

```
$('#nw_scroll_down').bind( "touchstart", function(e){
      scrolling = setInterval(function() {
      $('.mod_article').scrollTop( $('.mod_article').scrollTop() + 5 );
    },25); 
});

$('#nw_scroll_down').bind('touchend', function(){
  if (scrolling) {
    window.clearInterval(scrolling);
    scrolling = false;
  }
});
```

In order to make it work in both, desktop and touch devices, you can try this:

```
$('#nw_scroll_down').on("mousedown touchstart", function(e){
```

.

## Update

---

Another solution [given by Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW6) seems to be to add the inline event `onclick="void(0)"` to the element in which you have the `mousedown` event.

> A clickable element is a link, form element, image map area, or any other element with mousemove, mousedown, mouseup, or onclick handlers. A scrollable element is any element with appropriate overflow style, text areas, and scrollable iframe elements. Because of these differences, you might need to change some of your elements to clickable elements, as described in [“Making Elements Clickable,”](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW6%29) to get the desired behavior in iPhone OS.

Comment: yeah that does work for me, altough i dont think the onclick="void(0)" does anything usefull. should this prevent the context-menu to save the picture from popping up? is there any other knowen way to prevent it?

Comment: html {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}

that did the trick for me